# In mvc4 i am using grid view but it is showing error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@model IEnumerable<gridview.Models.emp>
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5,
selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
}
```

but here it is showing error like

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'WebGrid' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   c:\Users\anand.kumar\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\gridview\gridview\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    3   20  gridview

Comment: Then add the assembly (`System.Web.Helpers`)

Answer (score 0):

Add the Reference `System.Web.Helpers` to your project and Rebuild the project.

Try this:

```
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
```

has to be added in web config, under `system.web` section, withing `compilation` tags so it will look like:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

**OR**

1) Open `NuGet Package Manager` in `Visual Studio` and search *“microsoft-web-helper”* and install.

2) After installing it open `web.config` in your solution and change `connectionStringName` parameter for `DefaultMembershipProvider`, `DefaultRoleProvider` ve `DefaultSessionProvider` (if you do not, you might encounter 'DefaultConnection' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.” error.

3) Rebuild your project and then use a smilar definition like below in your razor view.

**OR**

1) Just add reference to `System.Web.Helpers 2.0.0.0 dll` which Basic template does not include by default.

2) After adding the reference, you need to open property for the dll and change **Copy Local** to **True**.

Comment: Edited the answer @AnandA

Comment: Remove the dll reference and try again the steps.

Comment: @using GridMvc.Html  and I also added in view but same error

Comment: Sir i am using mvc4

Comment: i remove all dll reference bot not working can u send any other example so i can relate the thing